# php_mvc example. Links producing 404 errors

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

(first question so please accept any etiquette fo-pars)

Im trying to get my head around PHP MVC so I thought Id try and look at the [php_mvc](http://www.php-mvc.net/) project.   Ive been through all the setup instructions and have the standard front page appearing nicely in the browser.

Whenever I try to click the links, I get a 404 error.

As far as I understand it, its because of the url changing characteristics of MVC(?)

Ive altered my .htaccess file as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /MCVxample/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L] 

</IfModule>


<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
 ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

Ive also setup my httpd.conf (using XAMPP3.2.1) file as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName symp.localhost
     DocumentRoot C:\xampp\htdocs
     SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
     <Directory C:\xampp\htdocs>
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Ive also made sure that the `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` line is uncommented.

Can anyone help with what Im doing wrong please?

thanks in advance

Matt

Comment: urrg. Fixed it. It was a typo in my .htdocs file..

id put RewriteBase /MCVxample/

instead of

RewriteBase /MVCxample/

what an eediot.

Comment: Your really shouldn't use that piece of code as an example. Aside from having nothing to do with MVC, it also contains extremely bad practices.

Comment: thanks for that.  can you highlight the practices as Ive used snippets from tutorial sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turned out to be a type after all of that.

Id put `RewriteBase /MCVxample/` instead of `RewriteBase /MVCxample/`